# GWT: label getOffsetHeight() value does not match the CSS value

Tags: css, gwt

In CSS I set the height of label to 19px. However, when I check the label's height using the `getOffsetHeight()` method, I receive sometimes 18 and sometimes 20 (never 19). The text in the label changes between each `getOffsetHeight` call.

I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Does your label have `display: inline;`? If yes, then the `height` attribute has no effect - it is determined by the label's contents then. (This is also true for other circumstances where "height" has no effect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `height` CSS property does not include padding, borders or margins. From [GWT javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetHeight%28%29) for `getOffsetHeight()`:

> Gets the object's offset height in pixels. This is the total height of
>   the object, including decorations such as border and padding, but not
>   margin.

So the increase in value you are seeing is because `getOffsetHeight()` is returning total height of the `Label`, including border and padding.

Comment: There is no border (border: none) and no padding